# Powershell word header replace

Tags: powershell

I want to replace header in word document.

```
$pth = "d:\test\test.docx"
$objWord = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$objWord.Visible = $True

$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open($pth)
$objSelection = $objWord.Selection

$Section = $objDoc.Sections.Item(1)
$header = $Section.Headers.Item(1)
```

This return me a plain text:

```
Write-Host $header.Range.Text
```

But my header have an image and table. Can i replace string in header without destroying header? I replace strings in word document and works great. My only problem is header.

Link to example Word document header below.

http://zapodaj.net/223c522426648.png.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$replaceWith = "New Text !"
$replace = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace]::wdReplaceAll
$findWrap = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap]::wdFindContinue

$find = $header.Range.find
$find.Execute($header.Range.Text, 
              $false, #match case
              $false, #match whole word
              $false, #match wildcards
              $false, #match soundslike
              $false, #match all word forms
              $true,  #forward
              $findWrap, 
              $null,      #format
              $replaceWith,
              $replace)
```

The pictures and other tables, should remain untouched.

Comment: This returning false and don't replace anything. But I don't want to replace all header but just single text in header. Creating own header in powershell is not solution because every header is different. I try to walkaround with VBA and it works in 95% (not all headers are replaced) but it's works only in Word document. I can't run VBA outside (probably it's possible to run from VBS but when I try it didn't work.)

Comment: This worked for me. However if you have a more complex situation, you might need to look into something like this : http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't know solution in powershell but I use VBA runed from powershell.

// code is changed so if it don't work let me know

```
$objWord = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$objWord.Visible = $True # don't have to be true

$pathToFile = "d:\Delivery_Templates\filename.docx" #path to your file

$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open(pathToFile )
$objSelection = $objWord.Selection

$objWord.Run('myReplace', [ref] $currentVersion); # myReplace - macro name, currentVersion - macro parameter
```